# Chameleon questions with answers for both meanings - what to do?

Tags: support, specific-question

[How do I create a link to the author's profile on the node that user created?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/108801/16495) was chameleoned and had two meanings.

1. [Original](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/revisions/108801/2) answered [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/108806/16495) and [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/108805/16495)
2. [Edited](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/revisions/108801/3) answered [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/108815/16495)

I don't see a way to edit this question in a way that will **not** render some of answers invalid, and all was valid at the time of posting.

What should be done there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, the question asks how to create a link; since the question didn't originally explained what kind of link the user wanted to create, the answer saying that the link to the node's author's profile page is automatically given from Drupal (when a setting is changed), and the answer saying how to add it programmatically are both correct.
There are answers that rely on a detail given in a revision, but removing that detail from the question doesn't make those answers less correct; I would take the text given for the link merely as example, which can be changed from the users who asked the question as his wills.

To make it short, reverting the question edit was correct, since it made some answers invalid; at the same time, removing that detail didn't make the new answers invalid.